# Passing Huge data between Vue js routes

Tags: javascript, url-routing, router, vue.js

I have an application which searches for flights using Vue.js and Vue Router.

I have two components, first one is search, which is on the base route '/'. When user clicks on search, it will send a request to server and gets a huge list of flights.

Then I need to call the result component on '/results' route and show the results using v-for.

I have two questions, first, how can I manually redirect to '/results' after I get the results.

Second and more important, what is the proper way of passing the results data to results component to use?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your results components, you can put transition hooks in the `route` object.  Read here:  http://vuejs.github.io/vue-router/en/pipeline/hooks.html

The `activate` hook runs when a component is activated, and the component wont appear until the activate hook has run.  Here's the example on that page, which would be similar to yours:

```
route:{
  activate: function (transition) {
    return messageService
      .fetch(transition.to.params.messageId)
      .then((message) => {
        // set the data once it arrives.
        // the component will not display until this
        // is done.
        this.message = message
    })
  }
}
```

So basically when they click search you send them to `/results` and this hook will handle loading the data in between.

Here's an advanced example of a mail app using `vue-router` that shows off a lot of the transition hooks in action: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/tree/dev/example/advanced

Comment: Thank you. Now I know how to access params from search component, but I can't set params of component, I tried  this.$route.b = this.a;  but it does not change it. I did it in ready function of search component.